# Azure. Connection to 40.117.211.214 closed by remote host

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-virtual-network

I am currently trying to access the VM on Azure for my Big Data course. I have already set up HortonWorks on Azure. When I try to access the VM from my Ubuntu command line with my password, I get the following error(s):'

```
isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ ssh isaacaktam@40.117.211.214
isaacaktam@40.117.211.214's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
isaacaktam@40.117.211.214's password: 
System is booting up. See pam_nologin(8)
Connection to 40.117.211.214 closed by remote host.
Connection to 40.117.211.214 closed.
```

And the following too:

```
isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ ssh -p 8888 isaacaktam@40.117.211.214
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

So, what do I need to do to solve this? Both of the above ports have everything as Any and *.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make sure that your username and password correct? This error mostly report the wrong password.

Comment: Hello there, both username and password are correct. For some reason, VM does not want to shake hands with my local machine.

Comment: Did you try to reset the username and password in Azure portal?

Comment: I reset password several times already.

Comment: I have done it several times already.

Comment: Do you have any other user that can login or only have the one? And after you create the VM, what else you have changed?

Comment: Created the other ports as described here:

http://www.oramoss.com/installing-hortonworks-data-platform-2-5-on-microsoft-azure/

This is a nightmare, I have been going at for over 2 days to no avail.

Comment: I follow the article you give me and do a test. First I got the same error, then I reset the username and password. And I ssh the VM with public IP or dns name and it's ok.

Comment: How did you reset username?

Comment: In the portal, find your vm resource, select the **Reset password** in left, **Reset password** mode and entry username and password, finally **Update** at the top.

Comment: The solution was to change the RAM size to 8 GB, wait 15-20 mins, and run the ssh again. Please close the thread.